# Rails capistrano deploy issue, Malformed version number string Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I'm not very familiar with ruby. I'm trying to deploy existing project to the staging server.

Project uses followings,
ruby 1.8.7
rails 2.3.5
rake 0.8.7
capistrano 2.5.13
capistrano-ext 1.2.1

When I run “cap staging deploy” in my project root, it fails with **Malformed version number string Capistrano::Version (ArgumentError)**

following is the console output,

```
/Users/sajithk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/version.rb:187:in `initialize': Malformed version number string Capistrano::Version (ArgumentError)
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb:8:in `new'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@global/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb:8
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
from ./config/deploy.rb:1:in `load'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from Capfile:4:in `load'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:64:in `load_recipes'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:64:in `each'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:64:in `load_recipes'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:30:in `execute!'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/capistrano-2.5.13/bin/cap:4
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/cap:19:in `load'
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/cap:19
from /Users/sajithk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue by myself. This might help someone else who came across same issue in the future.

The  issue was with the bundler. I have used the latest version of bundler. Since this is a older project, I seems the bundler is not compatible with them. I downgrade the bundler to 1.0.10. everything works ok now.

Commands used,

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler -v ‘1.0.10'
```

Thanks